# View Controller Transitions on ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem with a transition on my app. I have a menu view controller which is the root view. I have have a overview controller which is the 'main' controller offering options for users to move through the application. The overview controller has a button which slides the view to the right to display the menu controller behind it. the problem I have is that when the app launches i set the root view to the menu controller and then place the overview on top of that and when the app launches it flashes the menu controller before place the overview on top of it. My question is, is there any way to get rid of that flash? so can i push the overview on top of the menu before it appears? or show the overview and then add the menu underneath it?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You can put a check in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` on the basis of that you can set root view.

Comment: do you need something like facebook app?  it has slidebar on click of top left and top right button.

Comment: yeah something like that but the view underneath the slide bar is the root view